# VB.NET: Check if input in textbox is in string array

Tags: vb.net

```
Private Sub txtQty_GotFocus(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles txtQty.GotFocus
   Dim strItem As String
   strItem = txtItem.Text
   Dim strArray As String
   strArray = itemArr(1)

   If String.Compare(strItem, strArray) = True Then
       MessageBox.Show("item in array!")
   End If
End Sub

Private Sub txtQty_TextChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles txtQty.TextChanged

    If txtItem.Text <> Nothing And txtQty.Text <> Nothing Then

        'create rows in the DataTable
        tblScItem.Rows.Add(itemArray())
    End If

    txtItem.Text = ""
    txtQty.Text = ""

End Sub
```

This is how i declare my array:

```
Function itemArray() As String()

        itemArr(0) = ""
        itemArr(1) = txtItem.Text
        itemArr(2) = Form2.cbGondola.SelectedItem
        itemArr(3) = txtQty.Text
        itemArr(4) = DateTime.Now
        itemArr(5) = Form1.txtLoginId.Text

        Return itemArr
End Function
```

I dont seem to do a proper check, help!

Comment: `Dim strArray As String`. What a horrible naming. That not an array but a string.

Comment: Where do you declare `itemArr`?

Comment: @Guffa I declared in the itemArr in:                           Module globalVariable

    Public itemArr(5) As String

End Module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`String.Compare` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/84787k22.aspx) doesn't return a boolean, it returns an integer.

If the strings are equal, it returns `0`.

```
If String.Compare(strItem, strArray) = 0 Then
```

You should set `Option Strict` to `On` in your project, so that the compiler won't allow the implicit conversion from boolean to integer.

Comment: +1 for Option Strict!  However, all that really needs to be done is `If txtItem.Text = itemArr(1) Then`

Comment: @StevenDoggart I will try both methods and see how it goes, thanks!

Comment: @user1699905: Using the `=` operator also works. I just wanted to show exactly why the code that you have doesn't work as you expected.